# calculate values between two pandas dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

EDITED: let me copy the whole data set

df is the store sales/inventory data

```
  branch   daqu store     store_name       style  color  size  stocked    sold  in_stock  balance
0  huadong  wenning  C301  EE #��#��##��  EEBW52301M     39   160        7    4         3       -5
1  huadong  wenning  C301  EE #��#��##��  EEBW52301M     39   165        1    0         1        1
2  huadong  wenning  C301  EE #��#��##��  EEBW52301M     39   170        6    3         3       -3
```

dh is the transaction (move 'amount' from store 'from' to 'to')

```
    branch      daqu  from    to       style  color  size  amount  box_sum
8   huadong  shanghai  C306  C30C  EEOM52301M     59   160       1      162
18  huadong  shanghai  C306  C30C  EEOM52301M     39   160       1      162
25  huadong  shanghai  C306  C30C  EETJ52301M     52   160       9      162
26  huadong  shanghai  C306  C30C  EETJ52301M     52   155       1      162
32  huadong  shanghai  C306  C30C  EEOW52352M     19   160       2      162
```

What I want is the store inventory data after the transaction, which would look exactly the same format as the df, but only 'in_stock' numbers would have changed from the original df according to numbers in dh.

below is what I tried:

```
df['full_code'] = df['store']+df['style']+df['color'].astype(str)+df['size'].astype(str)    
dh['from_code'] = dh['from']+dh['style']+dh['color'].astype(str)+dh['size'].astype(str)
dh['to_code'] = dh['to']+dh['style']+dh['color'].astype(str)+dh['size'].astype(str)


# subtract from 'from' store
dh_from = pd.DataFrame(dh.groupby('from_code')['amount'].sum())

for code, stock in dh_from.iterrows() :
    df.loc[df['full_code'] == code, 'in_stock'] = df.loc[df['full_code'] == code, 'in_stock'] - stock

# add to 'to' store    
dh_to = pd.DataFrame(dh.groupby('to_code')['amount'].sum())

for code, stock in dh_to.iterrows() :
    df.loc[df['full_code'] == code, 'in_stock'] = df.loc[df['full_code'] == code, 'in_stock'] + stock

df.to_csv('d:/after_dh.csv')
```

But when I open the csv file then the 'in_stock' values for those which transaction occured are all blanks.
I think `df.loc[df['full_code'] == code, 'in_stock'] = df.loc[df['full_code'] == code, 'in_stock'] + stock` this has some problem. What's the correct way of updating the value?

---

ORIGINAL: I have two pandas dataframe: df1 is for the inventory, df2 is for the transaction

df1 look something like this:

```
   full_code in_stock
1  AAA       200
2  BBB       150
3  CCC       150
```

df2 look something like this:

```
   from   to   full_code  amount
1  XX     XY   AAA        30
2  XX     XZ   AAA        35
3  ZY     OI   BBB        50
4  AQ     TR   AAA        15
```

What I want is the inventory after all transactions are done.
In this case,

```
   full_code in_stock
1  AAA       120
2  BBB       100
3  CCC       150
```

Note that full_code is unique in df1, but not unique in df2.
Is there any pandas way of doing this? I got messed up with the original dataframe and a view of the dataframe and got it solved by turning them into numpy array and finding matching full_codes. But the resulting code is also a mess and wonder if there is a simpler way of doing this not turning everything into a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to set the index in `df1` to the 'full_code' column and then call `sub` to subtract the other df.

What we pass for the values is the result of grouping on 'full_code' and calling `sum` on 'amount' column.

An additional param for `sub` is `fill_values` this is because product 'CCC' does not exist on the rhs so we want this value to be preserved, otherwise it becomes `NaN`:

```
In [25]:

total = df1.set_index('full_code')['in_stock'].sub(df2.groupby('full_code')['amount'].sum(), fill_value=0)
total.reset_index()
​
Out[25]:
  full_code  in_stock
0       AAA       120
1       BBB       100
2       CCC       150
```

Comment: Thank you, and one more question: actually in df1 I have many more columns. This code throws away all the columns except the full_code and in_stock, is there any other way to keep them alive?

Comment: You could just assign/merge this result back to your df, so using the above code you could do `df1.merge(total.reset_index(), on='full_code')` I think should work

Comment: I tried `df1 = df.set_index('full_code')['in_stock'].sub(dh_final.groupby('full_code')['amount'].sum(), fill_value=0)
    df1.reset_index()
    df1.columns = ['full_code', 'in_stock']
    print type(df1)
    print df1.head(5) ` but it gives `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
full_code
C301EEBW52301M39160    3
C301EEBW52301M39165    1
C301EEBW52301M39170    3
C301EEBW52301M51160    1
C301EEBW52301M51165    1
Name: in_stock, dtype: float64` I wonder why df.sub() returns a series instead of a dataframe...

Comment: If your starting df only had 2 columns and you then set 1 of them as the index, this may convert it to a Series is my guess